# Как избавиться от прилипания персонажа при упоре в препятствие?

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть проблема с падением в unity. Если персонаж впреться в плафтформу боком при это под ногами у него нету ничего он прекращает падать. Нужно это убрать. Для игрока использую Box Colider и Circle Colider. Для плафтормы Box Colider.

[image: колайдеры]

колайдеры

[image: застрявший]

застрявший

Вот как перемещается персонаж:

```
void Update() {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.right * moveX *speed*Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && numberon>0) 
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 8000);//numberon проверка стоит ли персонаж на платформе
}
```

Comment: добавьте скрин на котором видны коллайдеры

Comment: и застрявший плз

Comment: а как Вы двигаете персонажа?

Comment: Нужно в матрице взаимодействия коллайдеров убрать взаимодействие между верхним квадратным коллайдером и коллайдерами платформ.

Comment: А можно подробнеё что за матрица где её брать. Я сегодня только в unity пришёл.

Comment: А для чего нужен квадратный коллайдер?

Comment: Коллайдер(если он не триггер) начертывает границы через которые не может пройти другой коллайдер.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне не нужно объяснять, как работают коллайдеры, я спросил, для чего **в вашей игре** он используется.

Comment: Я просто изучаю юнити и пробовал сделать управление персонажем. Квадратный коллайдер чтоб персонаж не проходил сквозь другие обьекти круглый коллайдер для перемещения персонажа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заставить персонажа "скользить" вниз при упоре в препятствие и отсутствии земли под ногами можно следующим образом:

1. Создайте Material, настроенный под скольжение. Для этого нажмите ПКМ на пустом месте во вкладке "Project" -> Create -> Physics Material 2D. Затем установите значение 0 для обоих полей[image: Должно получиться так]
2. Добавьте вашему персонажу по бокам 2 коллайдера типа **EdgeCollider2D**. С помощью "Edit Collider" расставьте точки коллайдера так, чтобы он был "снаружи" основного коллайдера персонажа и зрительно не касался его (см. скрин).[image: По 1 коллайдеру с каждой стороны.] Важно, чтобы коллайдеры были именно по бокам персонажа - если сделать такие коллайдеры под ногами, то персонаж начнёт ожидаемо скользить по поверхностям.
3. Теперь добавьте созданный вами материал (из п. 1) на оба коллайдера (в поле **Material**) и можете начинать радоваться - теперь ваш персонаж будет скользить боками об препятствия, словно намазан маслом, а не прилипать к ним.

Данный материал означает реакцию "скольжения" при столкновении. То есть, его можно нацепить на любой коллайдер, по которому персонаж должен будет скользить.